# How to enable horizontal scrolling in ListView in WinRT

Tags: listview, scrollview, winrt-xaml

I am creating a Windows 8.1 application and I have a list view where every row can extend beyond the screen limits. I want to allow the use to scroll left and right when the row is wide, but I can't seem to get the horizontal scroll viewer to appear event when setting its properties explicitly.

```
    <ListView
        ItemsSource="{Binding AllColors}"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
        > 
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="3600"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle Height="100">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <LinearGradientBrush>
                            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Black"/>
                            <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="{Binding}"/>
                            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="White"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

The horizontal scroll bar appears, but it does not allow scrolling (as if there is no need to...) while the items inside it are much wider then the screen.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Did you try to set the width of the `ItemsPanel` too?

Answer (score 0):

Setting these to Auto should be enough

```
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
```

Maybe your `ListView` is hosted in a horizontal `StackPanel` or another `ScrollViewer`?

Comment: thanks for your answer, please see the question, I am setting these properties there, setting them to auto does not solve the problem. Also, no, the ListView is not hosted in a stack panel or a scroll viewer, it is hosted in a grid. The problem is not that virtualization is lost, but rather that there is no horizontal scroll.

Comment: I know, I saw you set these. I'm saying you should not set the other things. It's possible that causes problems. I just set these on a ListView and it started scrolling both ways.

Comment: But I *Need* the other settings as well. I need to stretch the content and also to use the ItemsStackPanel...